# How can i use the base django base permissions to limited user access?

Tags: django, authentication, permissions, django-rest-framework

Can someone explain with an example or a tutorial of how can i allow model's view using the permissions that this user has.
for example i have 2 users and 6 tables (models), I set that each one have permission for 3 tables, when the user access through the api authentication just allow access to the tables that he has permissions.

PD: sorry i don't speak english.

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears that you're using django-rest-framework, I recommend you look at the [documentation on permissions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/) for django-rest-framework. Specifically, the section you will want is [DjangoModelPermissions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangomodelpermissions).

An example of how you would implement this (assuming a class based view) would look like:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import DjangoModelPermissions
from rest_framework.views import APIView

from .models import MyModel


class MyView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (DjangoModelPermissions,)
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
```

Keep in mind that, as stated in the documentation, you must provide a `queryset` attribute on the view class in order for this to work.